# how to run server flask in other ip address on mac

Tags: python, flask, server

I am trying to run office server python flask on local using vpn server, I run with command `pyhton3 -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0` The output successfully goes as follows.

```
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in production deployments. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Runs on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Runs at http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Runs at http://172.20.3.120:5000
```

Then I tested it in postman like this
`http://172.20.3.120:5000/api/v1/predict`

But the result is failure and error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.20.3.120:5000
```

I have looked for various solutions, one of which is turning off the firewall, I have turned it off but it still doesn't work. Is there any other way? I use macOS

Comment: Do you have the port 5000 opened with your firewall?

Comment: I don't know, I just turn off firewall on security setting

Comment: the modem needs to forward incomming traffic on that port (some ISP's disable this) ... then your router also needs to forward the traffic ...  you can use ngrok to easily make your home site accessible for a short while to the whole internet

Comment: I cannot using ngrok, because the server is private for internal office